# In an intrinsic semiconductor, are there the same number of carrier electrons and holes? Or this is just exclusive for silicon?

Tags: solid-state-physics, electric-current, semiconductor-physics, material-science, charge-carrier

I am working with some polymers that behave like semiconductors when they are plugged into the current.

I am calculating the mobility of these polymers and I need the value of the current density (J) in order to achieve it.

I have found that the current density is the sum of the Jp+Jn.

Therefore, since for an intrinsic semiconductor the number of n and p is the same, then for Jp should I divide the total J by 2 or does this only apply to inorganic semiconductors?

Comment: Polymer semiconductors really aren't my thing, but the conduction mechanisms are decidedly different along a molecule backbone vs in a crystal. However, even in, say, silicon, the electron and hole currents are not necessarily equal, since the mobility of the two is different.

Answer (score 1):

The equal number of free electrons and holes is a general property of intrinsic semiconductors. It does not matter whether kind of material you consider.

However, the same volumetric density does not imply the same electron/hole current. They might have different mobilities according to each particular material.